# How to associate trace on finite fields with linear algebraic trace

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, trace-map

I am familiar with the partial trace operator that one deals with in Quantum computing on density matrices. That would be sum of diagonal elements. I was reading a section on finite fields and polynomials that defined a trace operation from prime subfield ($\mathbb{F}_{p^t}$)to the base field ($\mathbb{F}_{p}$) as follows:

$$
\text{tr}[a] = \sum_{l=0}^{t-1} a^{p^l}
$$

I am unable to relate this to the intuition I am familiar with, can someone provide me with some explanation how I can connect this with the linear algebraic definition of trace

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if $L$ is a finite [field extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension) of a field $K$ of degree $n$, meaning that $K \subset L$ and the dimension of $L$ as a vector space over $K$ is $n$, then we can associate to any $a \in L$ the left multiplication operator

$$M_a : b \mapsto ab$$

which is a $K$-linear map $L \to L$ and hence which defines an element of $\text{End}_K(L) \cong M_n(K)$ (where this identification comes from choosing some basis of $L$ over $K$). Then we can define a $K$-valued trace for elements of $L$ by defining

$$\text{tr}_{L/K}(a) = \text{tr}(M_a).$$

This trace can be computed in any basis and [does not depend on the choice of basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Trace_of_a_product). It is equal to the sum of the roots of the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) of $M_a$.

If furthermore $L$ is a finite [Galois extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_extension) of $K$ with Galois group $G$, then the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $M_a$ turn out to be $ga$ as $g$ runs across all elements of $G$, from which it follows that

$$\text{tr}_{L/K}(a) = \sum_{g \in G} ga.$$

Finally, $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is a finite Galois extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$ of degree $n$ with Galois group the cyclic group of order $n$ generated by the [Frobenius map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism) $x \mapsto x^p$, from which it follows that

$$\text{tr}_{\mathbb{F}_{p^n}/\mathbb{F}_p}(a) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a^{p^i}$$

as desired.